# Amusing 404 Page Not Found Image?

Tags: discussion, top-7

I don't know if you've noticed, but each SO "Trilogy" site's 404 (Page Not Found Error) has its own on-topic amusing image.  This site currently has the boring "PAGE NOT FOUND :(" that every beta SE site has ([check it out if you don't believe me](https://gis.stackexchange.com/fourohfour)).

So, following the lead of other betas, I'm starting this question to gather ideas for amusing 404 Page Not Found images.

To clarify exactly what we're looking for, here's a quote showing what Jeff was originally looking for [when he asked for ideas on  the SO trilogy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites/):

> By on topic, I mean the 404 image on
>   Stack Overflow should be a programmery
>   "not found" of some kind, and the
>   Super User one should be a power
>   user's "not found", and so forth.

So a photography-related "problem" or inside joke for this site would be funny...

More from Jeff (my edit in [brackets]):

> These images would be shown in
>   addition to the existing 404 page
>   text, so nothing is getting lost,
>   we're just trying to inject a little
>   fun into the process.
>
> I'm having trouble coming up with
>   anything. Any good suggestions? Post
>   them as answers!
>
> If your submission or suggestion is
>   highly voted and meets the criteria
>   outlined, it's likely to be deployed
>   as the "official" 404 image for [this site] …

Please post the image AND quote the source so the dev team can negotiate rights if necessary.

[(Vote on other Site Attributes)](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/)

Answer (score 6):

## [Hic Sunt Dracones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons)

This would seem to fit the 404 idea to a T:

> "Here be dragons" is a phrase used to denote dangerous or unexplored territories, in imitation of the medieval practice of putting sea serpents and other mythological creatures in blank areas of maps.
>
> ### History
>
> The only known historical use of this phrase is in the Latin form "HC SVNT DRACONES" (i.e. hic sunt dracones) on the [Lenox Globe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenox_Globe) (ca. 1503-07). Earlier maps contain a variety of references to mythical and real creatures, but the Lenox Globe is the only known surviving map to bear this phrase.
>
> The term appeared on the Lenox Globe around the east coast of Asia, and might be related to the [komodo dragons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_dragon) in the Indonesian islands, tales of which were quite common throughout East Asia.
>
> The classical phrase utilized by ancient Roman and Medieval cartographers used to be HIC SVNT LEONES (literally, Here are lions) when denoting unknown territories on maps.
>
> — Here be dragons, from Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

This is a crop from the map that Wikipedia uses on [Here be dragons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons).  It doesn't actually say "here be dragons", so it may be a bit confusing.

[image]

A picture of the Lenox Globe would be nice, but I can't find a good picture where it says the catchphrase, let alone a free one available.

How about something like a retro-LOLcat with said (Komodo) dragons?

[image]

Here's the [source image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Parthkomodo.jpg), but I don't really care much for that one as the background is too busy (but it's a baby, awww, cute...).  There are plenty of other free [Komodo dragon pictures on the Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Varanus_komodoensis) though.

Answer (score 5):

Again, I don't have copyright for this particular image, but it could be easily recreated, etc.:

[image]

Source: http://www.outdoorsshowextra.co.uk/the_show_2010/visitorinformation/

Comment: It'd be useful to add the source so rights can be negotiated, if required.

Comment: There are plenty of replacements for this available (for a small fee) from gettyimages and istockphoto

Answer (score 3):

I don't have copyright for this particular image, but could create a similar one if we like it:

[image]

Source: http://www.outdoorsshowextra.co.uk/the_show_2010/visitorinformation/

Comment: haha very nice.

Comment: this one is freely usable (wikimedia commons): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Watson_Lake_Signpost.jpg
I can arrange for a different angle or focus if need be.

Answer (score 2):

What about an image which shows Google Map's ability to lose islands or major cities.  It would be appropriate considering that both Google's problem and our 404 errors are both caused by computers.  (Okay, that might be a simplification)

Sources:

Google loses Sunrise, FL
http://www.cnn.com/2010/TECH/web/09/22/google.lost.sunrise.florida/index.html?eref=mrss_igoogle_cnn

These two images of Beaver Island not showing up in Maps, but existing in Satellite view, could make for an amusing animation.
http://cartastrophe.wordpress.com/tag/misleading/

Comment: I like this idea a lot, although I'd rather have a static image with an iconic piece of geography missing - something that would be immediately noticeable for people from all over the world.  Not sure we'd be able to use the Google Maps images, anyway, for copyright reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an image of the earth and someone trying to plot on a unexistent coordinate, in space?

Comment: Good idea, who has the talents to create a nice looking one?

Comment: That is a whole different thing :P

Answer (score 1):

These photos, from an amusingly ironic road trip in Arizona, might be good:

[image]

[image]

I own these images, so "negotations" would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: these are very nice too!

Answer (score 1):

Or, of course, there is always the lolcat option:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like a you-are-here map showing the 404.